# Extending Entity Model

Tags: entity-framework

We have a EMD from some SQL Database. Over this Model we create some CLASSES.

Now we want extend our project...this implicates adding some new columns in CLIENTE table on the database and extend CLASSES to work with this new columns.

Question is there any way to extend the EMD model or we have to build it from scratch an lose  the CLASSES functionality by inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Targeting .NET 3.5? It's difficult to work with the conceptual model. I rather follow these steps since I always end up having to do them anyways:

1. Delete the entity framework connection string from app or web config
2. Delete the model
3. Regenerate a new model when you are finished with changing the database

If you have a lot of customized names etc this is a lot of work. I know there are workarounds but I rather changes the names of the tables and columns in the database to suite my needs. If your main work is in custom partial classes you should be fine.

If it's EF 4 you are targeting it's fine to just go nuts.